# Angular2 rxjs missing observable.interval method

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use the interval method of an observable but I keep getting the error

```
 Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
```

I added these imports:

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";
import "rxjs/observable/IntervalObservable";
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You need to import the `Observable` class this way to be able to use the `interval` method:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

or

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
```

Comment: From the error message you can already understand that I have the Observable class imported...
And Like I said in my question I already have the import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval'; imported.

Comment: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` works for sure ;-) It's this for the other approach:`import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';`.

Comment: The observable.d.ts doesn't even contain the interval method as of angular2 beta, so that makes no sense, in any case that does not solve the problem as I already did that before opening the question.

Comment: Which version do you use Angular / Rxjs? It works for me Angular2 RC1 and Rxjs 5.0.0-beta.6...

Comment: `interval.d.ts` within the folder `rxjs/add/observable` folder contains the static method declaration: `import { IntervalObservable } from './IntervalObservable';
export declare const interval: typeof IntervalObservable.create;`

Comment: I tried to use it a a non static method, for the life of me I cant understand why would you make this a static method.

Comment: @DavidLimkys This is what screwed me up too. Why is not an instance method?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to create an `interval` (Observable) with `rxjs v6.2.1`:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
// instead of:
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

const counter = interval(1000); 

// instead of:
// const counter = Observable.interval(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible too, for:

"rxjs": "6.3.3"
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const myNumber = interval(1000);
    myNumber.subscribe(
      (number: number) => {
        console.log(number);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx'
```

```js
  printX:number;
  ngOnInit() {
    const myInterval = Observable.interval(1000);
    myInterval.subscribe((x : number)=>{
      this.printX=x;
    });

    }
```

Comment: How is this any different from Thierry Templier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37074714/369450)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
//This would help 'rxjs/add/observable/interval'
//import interval from 
ngOnInit() {
    const myNumber = Observable.interval(1000);
    myNumber.subscribe(
      (number: number) => {
        console.log(number);
      }
    );
```