# Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code inside the constructor of my Angular2 component class:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3]).interval(2000).subscribe(e=>{
         console.log(e);
       });
```

I imported the following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
```

I have the following error message while building my project using Angulat CLI:

```
Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, there is no such interval operator. There is a static factory function, though: Observable.interval(10). http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval

Comment: Thanks. But what is the alternative to get the array elements emitted in certain interval one by one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074485/angular2-rxjs-missing-observable-interval-method/37074714

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. The [`interval`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval) method is a static method that exists only on the `Observable` class. In other words, it's not an operator.

So you probably want `delay` or `timeout` instead.

```
Observable.from([1,2,3])
    .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val).delay(2000))
```

Comment: Yes, you made me understood interval cannot be used, thanks. But what is the alternative to get the array elements emitted in certain interval one by one? (delay & timeout seems delaying the whole sequence by certain time)

Comment: @coder That's a common misunderstanding of how to use the `delay` operator. All values are emitted one after another and also the delay applied one after another without waiting for the previous item to be reemited. So you'll have to use for example `concatMap()` to wait until the previous value was delayed and then continue. See the my update.

Comment: @coder please take a look at this question it you help you. [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572854/property-interval-does-not-exist-in-the-type-observable/50438416)