# Property interval does not exist in the type observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
     Observable.interval(3000).timeInterval().subscribe()=>{};    
}
```

Trying to invoke the Observable.interval() method it is throwing a compiler error 
"Property interval does not exist in the type observable".

Edit

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Note that the import statement is already included

Answer (score 40):

For RxJS 6+ the answer given by Tomasz Kula only applies when using the `rxjs-compat` package, which should only be used when in the process of converting an application from RxJS 5 to RxJS 6.

Within RxJS 6+, use:

```js
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

interval(3000).subscribe(x => /* do something */)
```

Note that any `Observable` creation function that previously existed on the `Observable` type, should now be imported from `'rxjs'`.

Answer (score 12):

this is correct for angular 6.1.+ and rxjs 6.2.+

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

 interval(1000).subscribe(
         (value: number) => {
           this.secondes = value;
         },
         (error: any) => {
           console.log('error');
         },
         () => {
           console.log('observable completed !');
         }
       );
```

Comment: How to unsubscribe this ?

Comment: Assign it into a variable and then `that_variable.unsubscribe();`

Answer (score 11):

for rxjs 5.5.2+ it is:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
```

usage:

```
interval(3000).subscribe(x => // do something)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

// here 20 (secs) is a reference till when it will get completed
 interval(1000).pipe(takeWhile(value => value < 20)).subscribe(
         (value: number) => {
           this.secondes = value;
         },
         (error: any) => {
           console.log('error');
         },
         () => {
           console.log('observable completed !');
         }
       );
```

This is a answer to how to unsubscribe.