# Expire time Countdown in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to implement similar but my requirement is little different.

[Countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437328/countdown-timer-in-angular-6)

I get Expiry time(in seconds, lets say 500 seconds) from database and displaying in Data Grid. The expiry time is one of the columns in Data Grid.

I want to implement countdown in Column and when time comes down to 30 seconds, I want to change column color to yellow and to red in 10 seconds.

How can I implement after getting data from database. Here is my existing code.

```
 this.service
  .GetsTransactions()
  .subscribe(
    (response: Model[]) => {
      this.transactionsData = response;
    },
    error => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Your code snippet is just a HTTP call. This is not an attempt to solve the issue.

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius My issue is after populating grid, how we even get start with making template of the column

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what grid are you talking about. Please show your attempt