# Angular 6: Observable HTTPClient

Tags: angular

I have an existing Angular 2 project that I ported to Angular 6 and now my HTTP-observable is not running any longer. As far I read it is about different operations of the new observable.

My service returns an observable. This I subscribe in the component and set interval and startindex.

How can I do that in Angular 6?

```typescript
// SERVICE 
@Injectable ()
export class ViewService
{
  constructor (private http : HttpClient)
  {      }

  foo () : Observable <any>
  {
    return this.http.get ("http://blabla",
      {responseType: "json"});
  }
}



// COMPONENT
export class ViewComponent
{
  constructor (private vs : ViewService)
  {      }

  ngOnInit ()
  {
    this.vs.foo ().interval (1000).startWith (0).subscribe (
      (resp) =>
      {
      });
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Error: error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'

Using rxjs 6.0.0

Comment: has any error ?

Comment: What is you current RxJs version right now ?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: You may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885710/6261137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to import `interval` from `rxjs`.

```typescript
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
```

Import `startWith` and also you have to import `mergeMap` from `rxjs/operators`.

```typescript
import { startWith, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then you could use them like this:

```typescript
interval(1000).pipe(
  startWith(0),
  mergeMap(iRes => this.vs.foo())).subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp);
  });
```

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of breaking changes in RxJS v6 that has been adopted by Angular6 that you need to be aware of:

1. The different way of import statement of observables and operators. So you will need to add operators in this way at the top of the component controller:

   ```
   import { interval } from 'rxjs';
   import { startWith, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
   ```
2. Use pipe() as a method to chain your operators, the old way of chaining them will not work:

   ```
   // COMPONENT
   export class ViewComponent
   {
       constructor (private vs : ViewService) {}

       ngOnInit () {
          const obs$ = interval(1000).pipe( // This is your main observer chain
              startWith(0),
              mergeMap(res => this.vs.foo()) // This will start a sub-chain of observer that is isolated to your main chain
                 .subscribe(res => console.log('subscription of the sub-chain: ', res))
          )

          obs$.subscribe(res => console.log('subscription of main chain: ', res));
       }
    }
   ```

If you are still confusing, please watch the video from Ben Lesh and learn what has been changed in RxJS v6: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCXZhe6KsxQ